# Question about continuous function that changes signs an infinite number of times on an interval.

Tags: calculus, continuity

The function $g$ is continuous over $[a,b]$. I define a "trouble point" $x$ as follows: $\forall \delta>0$, the interval $[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ contains both points where $g$ is negative and points where $g$ is positive, as well as points $y \neq x$ for which $g(y)=0$. For example, $x=0$ is a "trouble point" for $g(x)=x\sin(\frac 1 x)$. $a$ and $b$ are considered "trouble points" if the same rule applies for $[a,a+\delta]$ and $[b-\delta,b]$, respectively.

My question is, if $g$ changes signs an infinite number of times on $[a,b]$, can there be an infinite number of "trouble points" on $[a,b]$, or must there be a finite number?

Comment: You might try $f(g(x))$ where $f(x)$ is the continuous extension of $x \sin(1/x)$ and $g(x)=d(x,C)$ for some infinite closed set $C$, perhaps the Cantor set?

Comment: @RobArthan I noticed that and then removed it.

Comment: Yeah, the point here does seem to be that you have points of both signs on infinitely small one-sided neighborhoods of a trouble point; otherwise a continuous function has a trouble point at every point where it changes sign.

Comment: I think you need to modify your definition a bit. What is stopping $0$ from being a trouble point of $f(x) = x$? For every $\delta > 0$, the set $[x - \delta, x + \delta]$ contains points where $f$ is positive and points where $f$ is negative.

Comment: I am confused--isn't this trivial, since any point where $g$ changes sign is by definition a trouble point?  Or maybe you have misstated the question?

Comment: Oh, I guess $g$ could have intervals where it is constantly $0$, to avoid trouble points.

Comment: I think the title (which talks about sign changes) contains a better description of the question than the body of the question. Can the OP please fix the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the set of trouble points can't be dense (do you see why?). However, if you take a discrete infinite subset of $[0, 1]$ say, $X = \{1, 1/2 , 1/3, 1/4, \ldots\}$, you can construct a continuous function $f$ that changes sign infinitely often near each $y \in X$ (modelled on the $x \sin(x)$ pattern adjusted and scaled to be $0$ for points $x$ that are not near $y$).